# Newsletter Signup CiviCRM Thinks Anonymous is Admin

Tags: email

I'm using CiviCRM 4.4.20 with Drupal 7.43.

I created a profile to use for newsletter sign-up. Instead of a person signing up being set to "pending" and getting an email, the person is directly signed up and no email confirmation is being sent.

One clue to the problem is that it says "Added by Admin." I would have expected it to say "Pending (by email). Note that I am logged out when running this test.

How can I get CiviCRM to set the sign-up to "pending" and receive an email with a link to confirm?

Ideas?

Comment: How are your users accessing the signup - via the usual newsletter signup link (e.g.,. www.example.com/civicrm/mailing/subscribe  ?  From what you describe it sounds like your profile is doing a straightforward addition to the group, and not a newsletter signup per se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. What I had done was, in the "Advanced Settings" section of the profile's general settings, I had selected, "Add contact to Group" and then selected the mailing-list enabled Group I wanted to use on the form. This method totally circumvents the opt-in email.

What I have done since is leave that advanced section alone. Instead, I've added a field to the profile for "Group(s)." Now the opt-in email is sent.

Comment: hi Shai - i think you can 'accept' your own answer so it gets the green tick